# how to print the result of an SQL Query from a PDO Object

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am using `PHP+PDO+MySQL` to run some queries.

**My queries are working fine, but i am not able to print or access the individual rows.**

Here is the sql query :

```
$sql = "SELECT BUS_ID FROM noname WHERE STAND_ID=:start and BUS_ID in (SELECT BUS_ID FROM noname WHERE STAND_ID=:end)";
```

When i execute and fetch the results i get this :

```
$result = $stmt->fetchALL(PDO::FETCH_CLASS);
print_r ($result);
```

Output :

```
Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [BUS_ID] => 1 ) [1] => stdClass Object ( [BUS_ID] => 2 ) )
```

From what i understand with my little PHP knoweledge is that this is an array.
So i tried :

```
foreach ($result as $row)
{
    echo $row["BUS_ID"];
}
```

But i got no result..!!
Please tell me on how to traverse this array and get my field/column members.

Comment: Its array of objects try `$row->BUS_ID`

Comment: You're echoing array of objects which will be done as `echo $row->BUS_ID;`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `$stmt->fetchALL(PDO::FETCH_CLASS);` is returning a array of objects.
To access properties of objects you should use `->`, so try this:

```
print $row->BUS_ID;
```

Inside your `foreach`.